# Manipulating the Page Numbers of Index Entries

Tags: imakeidx

I am creating document containing a list of quotations from a very long book, each quotation associated with a page number (from the book). I would like to create an index to the document containing the page numbers of the book itself, not the page numbers of the document I am creating. The following code generates a document with an index, all the entries pointing, naturally, to page number 1. I would like them, rather, to point to pages 5, 14, and 17.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}%

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2]

\setlength{\marginparsep}{-0.4em}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3em}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\nt}[1]{\reversemarginpar\marginpar{\begin{footnotesize}#1 \end{footnotesize}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{footnotesize}
Truly man is a marvelously vain, diverse, and undulating object.\nt{5}\index{Diversity}

I am almost ready to vow irreconcilable hatred against all democratic
rule.\nt{14}\index{Democracy}

What causes do we not invent for the misfortunes that befall us?\nt{17}\index{Causes}

\end{footnotesize}

\cleardoublepage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a personal MakeIndex style; if the name is the same as the main document's with extension `.mst` it will be automatically used.

In the style file we change the `delim_0` (for first level index items) and `delim_t` that's added at the end of each entry.

Finally, I define a wrapper for `\index` to use the book page given as argument. I reuse `\nt`, but you can use a different command in case you want to have notes without a corresponding index entry.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 "\\ignore"
delim_t "\\ignore"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}%

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=2]

\setlength{\marginparsep}{-0.4em}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3em}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}

\newcommand{\nt}[2]{%
  \reversemarginpar\marginpar{\footnotesize #1}%
  \index{#2@#2\bookpage{#1}}
}
\protected\def\bookpage#1{,~#1}
\protected\def\ignore#1\ignore{}

\begin{document}

Truly man is a marvelously vain, diverse, and undulating object.\nt{5}{Diversity}

I am almost ready to vow irreconcilable hatred against all democratic
rule.\nt{14}{Democracy}

What causes do we not invent for the misfortunes that befall us?\nt{17}{Causes}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `.ind` file will be

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item Causes\bookpage {17}\ignore1\ignore

  \indexspace

  \item Democracy\bookpage {14}\ignore1\ignore
  \item Diversity\bookpage {5}\ignore1\ignore

\end{theindex}
```

so you see how the typesetting works: `\bookpage` expands to `, <number>` and the part between `\ignore...\ignore` gets ignored.

Avoid `\begin{footnotesize}`.

Comment: Many thanks, egreg! Works beautifully.